# Online accounts not working, can't create one

Tags: 13.04, google, online-accounts

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I am trying to setup online accounts, i.e. google+. I click on google and the login window for google+ then shows up. However after a few seconds it reverts to the add account window.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7y38roe7lxv4rq/2013-08-18_1347.png) what you get?

Answer (score 6):

Try installing gnome-online-accounts:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-online-accounts
```

I had the same problem, and doing this it worked.

(I got this clue on this old bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/869341)

Comment: This still works in ubuntu 14.04. Thnx!

Comment: Indeed on lubuntu, there is nothing in the gnome-control-center.